# Percentage of reoccurring observations by group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data set of firm-employee through time, that looks like this

```
data.table(firm = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 8)), 
           employee = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6, NA, NA, 5, 6, 7, 8),
           year = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4)))

  firm employee_id year
    A        1    1
    A        2    1
    A        3    1
    A        4    1
    A        1    2
    A        2    2
    A        3    2
    A       NA    2
    B        5    1
    B        6    1
    B       NA    1
    B       NA    1
    B        5    2
    B        6    2
    B        7    2
    B        8    2
```

I want to calculate the percentage of employees from year==1 that were still working on year==2, for each firm.

The output should be like this

```
firm year continued_employees
 A    2     0.75
 B    2     1
```

I can do it in a loop for each year, using

`sum(employee_id[year==1] %in% employee_id[year==2]) / length(employee_id[year==1])`

but I have around 40k firms and 10 years of observations. Any thoughts on how to do it in a `dplyr` or `data.table` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a not-so-pretty `data.table` approach you could use for any number of firms and years:

```
years <- head(sort(unique(dt$year)), -1)
setNames(lapply(years, function(y) {
  dt[dt[(year == y), .(firm, employee)], on = .(firm, employee)][
    !is.na(employee), all(c(y, y+1) %in% year), by = .(employee, firm)][, 
      .(continued = mean(V1), year = y+1), by = firm]
}), paste("Year", years, sep="-"))

#$`Year-1`
#   firm continued year
#1:    A      0.75    2
#2:    B      1.00    2
```

Since you only have two years in your sample data, you only get a single list element in return.

Comment: perfect! I was missing on the first join, while trying to do it in a data.table syntax. Not pretty, though succint and efficient

Comment: Btw, you could use rbindlist on the result to get a single table output

Answer (score 1):

#### Join with shifted year

This is an approach using a kind of *self join* with a shifted year:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
# self join with shifted year
DT[.(firm = firm, employee = employee, year = year - 1), 
   on = .(firm, employee, year), cont := TRUE][]
# aggregate
DT[!is.na(employee), sum(cont, na.rm = TRUE) / .N, by = .(firm, year = year + 1)][
  # beautify result
  year <= max(DT$year)]
```

> ```
>      firm  year    V1
>    <char> <num> <num>
> 1:      A     2  0.75
> 2:      B     2  1.00
> ```

The first expression modifies `DT` to indicate continued employees:

> ```
>       firm employee  year   cont
>     <char>    <num> <num> <lgcl>
>  1:      A        1     1   TRUE
>  2:      A        2     1   TRUE
>  3:      A        3     1   TRUE
>  4:      A        4     1     NA
>  5:      A        1     2     NA
>  6:      A        2     2     NA
>  7:      A        3     2     NA
>  8:      A       NA     2     NA
>  9:      B        5     1   TRUE
> 10:      B        6     1   TRUE
> 11:      B       NA     1     NA
> 12:      B       NA     1     NA
> 13:      B        5     2     NA
> 14:      B        6     2     NA
> 15:      B        7     2     NA
> 16:      B        8     2     NA
> ```

#### Using `shift()`

Alternatively,  the `shift()` function can be used to compute the `cont` column.  The aggregation part is the same as with the join approach above. `shift()` requires to ensure the data are ordered by year.

```
DT[order(year), cont := shift(year, type = "lead") == year + 1, by = .(firm, employee)][
  !is.na(employee), sum(cont, na.rm = TRUE) / .N, by = .(firm, year = year + 1)][
    year <= max(DT$year)]
```

#### Benchmark

At the time of writing, three approaches have been proposed in addition to OP's own attempt using loops:

- by [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47459408/3817004)
- join with shifted year
- using `shift()`

The answer of [Jean Vuda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461287/3817004) is not considered in the benchmark as it is limited to 2 years.

According to the OP, the production data set consists of 40 k firms and 10 years of data. For a realistic benchmark, a sample data set of similar size is created:

```
n_firm <- 40000L
max_employee <- 10L
fluctuation_rate <- 0.2
n_year <- 10L
start_year <- 2001L

DT0 <- CJ(firm = sprintf("%06i", seq_len(n_firm)), 
          employee = seq_len(max_employee), 
          year = seq(start_year, length.out = n_year))
set.seed(123L)
n_row <- nrow(DT0)
DT0[sample.int(n_row, fluctuation_rate * n_row), employee := NA]
```

The sample data set consists of 4 M rows and can be visualised best after reshaping from long to wide format:

```
dcast(DT0[!is.na(employee)], firm + employee ~ year)
```

> ```
> Using 'year' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
>           firm employee  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010
>         <char>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
>      1: 000001        1  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010
>      2: 000001        2  2001  2002  2003    NA  2005  2006  2007    NA  2009    NA
>      3: 000001        3  2001  2002    NA    NA  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010
>      4: 000001        4  2001    NA    NA    NA  2005  2006  2007  2008    NA  2010
>     ---                                                                            
> 399996: 040000        6  2001  2002    NA  2004  2005    NA    NA    NA  2009  2010
> 399997: 040000        7    NA  2002    NA    NA  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010
> 399998: 040000        8  2001  2002  2003    NA    NA    NA  2007    NA    NA  2010
> 399999: 040000        9  2001  2002  2003    NA  2005  2006  2007  2008  2009    NA
> 400000: 040000       10  2001  2002  2003    NA    NA  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010
> ```

For benchmarking, the `microbenchmark` package is used because a check function can be passed to verify the results are identical:

```
my_check <- function(values) {
  values <- lapply(values, function(x) x[, dcast(.SD, firm ~ year, value.var = "continued")])
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) identical(values[[1]], x)))
}
```

The benchmark code:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dd = {
    dt <- copy(DT0)
    years <- head(sort(unique(dt$year)), -1)
    rbindlist(
      setNames(lapply(years, function(y) {
        dt[dt[(year == y), .(firm, employee)], on = .(firm, employee)][
          !is.na(employee), all(c(y, y+1) %in% year), by = .(employee, firm)][
            , .(continued = mean(V1), year = y+1), by = firm]
      }), paste("Year", years, sep="-"))
    )
  },
  join = {
    DT <- copy(DT0)
    DT[.(firm = firm, employee = employee, year = year - 1), 
       on = .(firm, employee, year), cont := TRUE][
         !is.na(employee), .(continued = sum(cont, na.rm = TRUE) / .N), 
         by = .(firm, year = year + 1)][
           year <= max(DT$year)]
  },
  shift = {
    DT <- copy(DT0)
    DT[order(year), cont := shift(year, type = "lead") == year + 1, 
       by = .(firm, employee)][
         !is.na(employee), .(continued = sum(cont, na.rm = TRUE) / .N), 
         by = .(firm, year = year + 1)][
           year <= max(DT$year)]
  },
  check = my_check,
  times = 3L
)
```

The benchmark results show that the *join* approach is 4 times faster than the *shift* approach and 8 times faster than docendo discimus's approach.

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>     dd 11.756114 11.919959 12.083042 12.083805 12.246506 12.409207     3   c
>   join  1.054293  1.239829  1.303971  1.425366  1.428810  1.432254     3 a  
>  shift  6.105725  6.105906  6.148136  6.106087  6.169342  6.232596     3  b
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach to do it:

```
dt<-dat[,list(all=.(unique(employee))), by=list(year,firm)]
dt<-dt[,list(year1=sapply(list(all),`[`,1), 
             year2=sapply(list(all),`[`,2)), by=firm]
dt[,uniqueN(mapply(intersect, year1, year2))/uniqueN(na.omit(unlist(year1))),by=firm]
```